# How to check if Cell has Integer on it?

Tags: excel, vba

How to check if a specific Column has Integer on each cell, and if it contains a string, Insert a blank cell to row in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested:

```
Dim row As Long
Dim col As Long

col = 4      ' Whatever column you want to check

For row = 1 To 100     ' How many rows you want to check
    If Not IsNumeric(Cells(row, col).Value) Then
        ' Do whatever you want to do in this case
    End If
Next row
```

If you clarify what you mean by "*Insert a blank cell to row in question*", I will try to update my solution.

Comment: tnx, to insert a new blank cell to front of non numeric one

Comment: So you want to move the non-numeric cell one position to the right and insert a blank cell in its place? Or just clear the cell to the left of the non-numeric one?

Comment: Tip: Integer is too small to be used for a Row counter try using Long to prevent overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can check even check with a forumla that the column contains no none-numbers only

```
=COUNTBLANK(AAA:AAA)-COUNTBLANK(B:B)=COUNT(B:B)
```

where I assume that column AAA:AAA is empty.

Answer (score 0):

A mix of the other answers for bigger data. 
It first checks if the colomn has none Numbers only and if not, checks where.

```
Dim row As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   'if you want the colomn B

If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("AAA:AAA")) - Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("B:B")) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("B:B")) Then
For row = 1 To LastRow     

    If Not IsNumeric(Range("B" & row).Value) Then
        ' Do whatever you want to do in this case
    End If
Next row
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function IsInt(i As Variant) As Boolean
'checks if value i is an integer. returns True if it is and False if it isn't
    IsInt = False
    If IsNumeric(i) Then
        If i = Int(i) Then
            IsInt = True
        End If
    End If
End Function

Function IsString(s As Variant) As Boolean
'checks if variable s is a string, returs True if it is and False if not
    IsString = True
    If s = "" Then
        IsString = False
    Else
        If IsNumeric(s) Then
            IsString = False
        End If
    End If
End Function



Sub CheckInts(c As Integer)
'c = column number to check
'goes through all cells in column c and if integer ignores, if string sets to ""

Dim r, lastrow As Integer
    
    lastrow = Sheet1.UsedRange.rows.Count 'find last row that contains data
    
    For r = 1 To lastrow
        If Not IsInt(Cells(r, c).Value) Then
            If IsString(Cells(r, c).Value) Then
                Cells(r, c).Value = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

then just call CheckInts passing in the column number you want to change
e.g. CheckInts(2) will change column 2